# Are the last two digits in an inventory suffix number?

Tags: numbers, suffixes

I am an artist and I use inventory numbers to track my work. An example of an inventory number would be 2012.035.17.24.07. The last 2 numbers indicate the the type of work it is.
07 indicates paper,
14 indicates sculpture,
21 indicates paintings,
And their categories.

May I call these last 2 numbers a suffix?

Comment: Does the rest of the inventory number have meaning without the "suffix"?

Comment: What if the numbering series includes a "final digit checksum" value? Then you'd have to say the [*antepenultimate*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/antepenultimate) and *penultimate* digits are an "**infix**". I think that's a figurative usage too far.

Comment: Is this a system you invented, or one shared by many artists?

Comment: If it's clear from context what you mean (and that it's the last 2 numbers), then go for it. If you ask someone "what is the suffix in 2012.035.17.24.07" then they may struggle to know if you're talking about the last 2 digits or some other portion. I can't find examples of this usage based on a quick search, but if you're describing your code and identify something as a "two-digit type-code suffix" that seems easily understood. (Is there some other place you can ask that may have more specialist knowledge?)

Answer (score 1):

You may call them what you like, but I would not call them a suffix.

I would call them a *segment* — specifically the *last segment* — in your numbering system.

See, for example, [About Planning Your Item Numbering System](https://help.sage300.com/en-us/2019/web/Subsystems/IC/Content/Setup/AboutPlanningYourItemNumberingSystem.htm)

Comment: Why would you not call them a suffix?

Comment: @StuartF — Because it’s only a suffix if it’s last. If you remove .07, then .24 is the suffix. If you add .1, then .07 is no longer the suffix.